# Export the HTML table to excel is not working in Internet Explorer 10/11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I will done export the HTML table to Excel is working fine in Chrome and Firefox but its does not working in Internet Explorer 10/11.

```js
        var tableToExcel = (function () {
            var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
                , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
                , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
                , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
            return function (table, name) {
                if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
                var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
                window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
            }
        })()
```

```css
.myTable { background-color:#eee;border-collapse:collapse; }
.myTable th { background-color:powderblue;color:black; }
.myTable td, .myTable th { padding:5px;border:1px solid #000; }
```

```html
<table border='1' id='testTable' width='100%' class='myTable'>
<tr>
  <td>Test01</td>
  <td>Test02</td>
  <tr>
</table>
 <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" class="btn" onclick="tableToExcel('testTable', 'test')"><i class="icon-file"></i> Execl</a>
```